# Scrollbar is not displayed in ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a concern with a combobox that I created in JavaFx, this is to be handled from a touch screen for a touch application, in this combobox the scroll bar is not always visible and it is impossible to download or move the information in the tried from the css and I have not succeeded. Is it possible to do it from the code or what do you recommend me to do with it? This is the code that I used to try to make it visible all the time that the ComboBox is deployed

```
 .combo-box-popup .list-view .scroll-bar:vertical .thumb
{
    -fx-max-width: 12px;
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-background-insets: 2, 0, 0;
    -fx-background-size: 20px,40px;
    -fx-background-position: center 5% , center 95%;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .scroll-bar .thumb:hover,
.combo-box-popup .list-view .scroll-bar .thumb:pressed{
    -fx-background-color: derive(black,90%);
    -fx-min-width: 12px;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .scroll-bar:horizontal .thumb,
.combo-box-popup .list-view .scroll-bar:vertical .thumb {
    -fx-background-color:derive(black,90%);
    -fx-min-width: 12px;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0, 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0em;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but `ComboBox` uses a `ListView`to display the items which uses a `VirtualFlow` that sets the `visible` property from code depending on the number of items it has to display.Values set from code have a higher precedence than values set from CSS.Therefore setting the visible property has no effect and even if it had the scrollbar would cover a part of the cell since`VirtualFlow` only considers the scrollbar in the layout,if it makes it visible.There doesn't seem to be a way around reimplementing the skin of `ListView` to make sure it does behave as desired and setting this skin from css.

Comment: What I found curious, is that by modifying one of the arguments of the virtual machine, this: '-Dcom.sun.javafx.touch = false' modifying it to false. The combobox bar reappears and remains static while you keep the combobox displayed.

Comment: @fabian the amount of values that are inside the combobox are 80, you can help me increase the width to the thumb of the scroll-bar vertical